# Springframework Data Elasticsearch unable to create object of class java.time.ZonedDateTime

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am using the RestHightCLient as recommended together with ElasticsearchRestTemplate. I am trying retrieve ZonedDateTime from elasticsearch but it seems the spring-data-elasticsearch is unable to create an object of the class ZonedDateTime. Anything wrong with the code snippets below and what are the additional configurations do I need to add.

Also, If I was to use the RestHighLevelClient directly without the use of the ElasticsearchOperations what will I need to do.

```
    @Bean
    @Override
    public RestHighLevelClient elasticsearchClient() {
        HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        httpHeaders.add("content-type", "application/json");
        ClientConfiguration clientConfiguration = ClientConfiguration
                .builder()
                .connectedTo("localhost:9200")
                .build();
        return RestClients.create(clientConfiguration).rest();
    }

    @Bean(name = {"elasticsearchTemplate"})
    public ElasticsearchOperations elasticsearhTemplate() {
        return new ElasticsearchRestTemplate(elasticsearchClient());
    }
```

```
Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.convert.ConversionException: could not create object of class java.time.ZonedDateTime] with root cause

java.time.DateTimeException: Unable to obtain LocalDate from TemporalAccessor: {YearOfEra=2020, DayOfMonth=25, OffsetSeconds=3600, MonthOfYear=8},ISO resolved to 16:46:47.891 of type java.time.format.Parsed
    at java.base/java.time.LocalDate.from(LocalDate.java:397) ~[na:na]
```

```
public class XXClass {
    ....

    @Field(type = FieldType.Date, format = DateFormat.custom, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS Z")
    private ZonedDateTime created = ZonedDateTime.now();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your pattern to use *uuuu* instead of *yyyy*; this [is documented here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/4.0.3.RELEASE/reference/html/#elasticsearch.mapping.meta-model.annotations), the change in Elasticsearch responsible for this: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/migrate-to-java-time.html#java-time-migration-incompatible-date-formats

BTW, you don't need

```
httpHeaders.add("content-type", "application/json");
```

The `@Json...` annotations are not needed for Spring Data Elasticsearch.